# How do I find out the entity classes each attribute belongs to in a projection class for JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have the following classes, with `PersonDto` being my projection:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {

    @Id
    private long personId;
    private String name;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class MyEmployee extends Person {
    private String company;
    // constructor, getters, setters 
}

@Entity
public class YourEmployee extends Person {
    private String lease;
    // constructor, getters, setters 
}

public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
    private String company;
    private String lease;

    public PersonDto(String name, String company, String lease) {
        this.firstName = name;
        this.lastName = company;
        this.lease = lease;
    }

    // getters, equals and hashCode
}
```

I want to find out which entity each attribute of `PersonDto` belongs to. I am trying to do something like:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PersonDto> criteria = builder.createQuery(PersonDto.class);

// Here I need to set the correct roots, but I'm not sure how, because PersonDto is passed as a generic argument.

// Because PersonDto has "company"
Root<MyEmployee> myEmployeeRoot = criteria.from(MyEmployee.class);
// Because PersonDto has "lease"
Root<YourEmployee> yourEmployeeRoot = criteria.from(YourEmployee.class);
```

With "name" I'm not sure how to find out which class it belongs to.

I think I can use `entityManager.getMetaModel()` or something to use `MyEmployee_` and `YourEmployee_`.

The issue is that I'm trying to dynamically set the `criteria.from` using only the projection class. Nothing else will be passed to the method I'm trying to achieve this in.

Comment: Hello! you could have a query per each class that extends Person. each query will return a collection of PersonDto. you add all result collection in a single one and return it.